# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when calling a function

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am wanting to write some code to return some data from an aJax call.

Here is the resource that I am referring to: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Here is the code that I have written:

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", function(result));
alert(data);

function getData(dataUrl, result)
{
    $.ajax({url: dataUrl, success: function(result){
        return result;
    }});
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

At this line of code:

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", function(result));
```

Also, is the above code efficient when getting large amounts of data?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, `function(result)` is the start of a function expression, but it's missing its body. The body [in which the `alert(result)` should go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572). Also that `return result` in your `success` callback doesn't exactly work.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `function(result)` to do?

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 (because of the first line), but I feel like your actual problem is lack of understand how callbacks (and maybe even functions) work in JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct syntax for a callback, plus the asynchronous call doesn't quite work like that. Try this instead - `data` is set in the callback.

```
var data;
getData("http://www.file.txt"); 

function getData(dataUrl)
{
    $.ajax({url: dataUrl, success: function(result){
        data = result;
        alert(data);            
    }});
}
```

Comment: Why that global `var data` variable?

Comment: `data` is just not quite global, just in whatever closure this fragment is in. `result` parameter because I missed it ;)

Comment: Sure, it's free ("global") to `getData`. Asynchronous calls don't work like that. There's no reason to have it in that scope (whichever scope that is).

Answer (score 0):

From JavaScript basics, a function should satisfy following.

1. A JavaScript function is defined with the function keyword, followed by a name, followed by parentheses ().
2. A function is basically a JavaScript object. So, The parentheses are required,as they set apart a function from the other items of your script or web page.

So the line of code is actually incorrect.

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", function(result));
```

It should be either of the below.

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", function(result) {
    //anonymous function body
});
```

or

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", callbackFn(result));

function callbackFn(result) {
    //function body goes here.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing brackets so you get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token)** error

```
var data = getData("http://www.file.txt", function(result){});
```

But I think you have to use function like this

```
function getData() {
  return Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

getData("http://www.file.txt").then(function(result) {
 console.log(result);
}).catch(function() {
  // an error occurred
});
```

Comment: it is just an example why op get error so i given explanation @bergi

Comment: But your example will throw an error because `result` is not defined. I don't think you are aware of what `callback(result)` in `var data = getData("http://www.file.txt",callback(result));` does.

Comment: op pass result in his function so i passed it and this  solution is for Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )   so i given explanation on it not for result and other stuff op asked for Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: oh yes you are right about  Promise issue so i edited my answer so if any one refers it will get proper solution not wrong one  thanks @FelixKling

Comment: @KevalBhatt: Now that's the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) :-/ Use `return Promise.resolve($.ajax(…))` (or don't cast to native promises at all)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ajax call, then you must use `success` or `.then` with it to be executed as callback after receiving data.

The code should be only this:

```
var data = '';
$.ajax({url: dataUrl, success: function(result){
        data = result;
        alert(data);
    }});
```

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between your code and the OP's code is?

Comment: As per my understanding of the question, what is needed is that he wants to execute some code as callback and assign the value to data. So as a result of success function, the result will be assigned to data.

Comment: OK, to be specific: `alert(data)` will alert the empty string, not the expected result.

Comment: alert(data) will be used after data is assigned result value.

Comment: Why did you place it in there (the OP did not)? Why use that `data` variable at all instead of just `alert(result)`?

Comment: The results stored in data variable can be used outside the ajax function as well, while the scope of result is limited, thus I assigned result to data. I may not be correct but this was what I understood of the question.

Comment: But if you placed the `alert(data)` outside of the ajax function callback, it wouldn't work, so apparently we cannot use the variable there.

Comment: Yes what you are saying is absolutely right and I know that too, but since there is no clear demarcation regarding the needs of the question, I alerted the received data. This was all the purpose of using that.